# Privacy Policy for Google Play Services in app

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, privacy-policy

Do I need to post a privacy policy for an android app that uses google play services such as in-app billing, cloud storage and leaderboards?
Also I use Admob but not currently google analytics.

From google website:

```
If your app handles personal or sensitive user data (including personally
identifiable information, financial and payment information, authentication
information, phonebook or contact data, microphone and camera sensor data, and
sensitive device data) then your app must:

Post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer
Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.
```

I do not believe I access any data that could identify a user's real identity or that is not already public.

If yes, any suggestions of where I can generate a free one or get a basic template?

Comment: what permissions are you using in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not process or store any user information by yourself but only by standard google services, you can go without privacy policy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Privacy Policy if you don't collect user data through third party, but keep in mind that AdMob by Google can enable "Interest-based advertising".

According to [AdMob Policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128543?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287&visit_id=1-636177757435708974-2003121124&rd=1), you need to disclose to end-users that your app integrates with third party tools (such as AdMob) that are using behavioral remarketing and how end-users can opt-out.

[Interest-based advertising policies clause by AdMob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyNEm.jpg)

Comment: Do the developer have to include the policy in the app instead of the profile page on Google Play Store?

Comment: That's generally a good practice. Example: https://termsfeed.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/zoom-app-settings-menu.jpg